# move delimted fields into Newline

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have the comma seperated txt file which must have five columns only, but the some of the rows have more than 5 column.
I want to move the 6th to 10th to a newline, and 11th to 15th to a newline so on

Below is the conetent of `input.txt`

```
1,2,3,4,5
12,13,14,15,16,11,17,18,19,20
22,23,24,25,26,22,27,28,29,21,30,31,32,33,34
```

Below is the conetent of `Output.txt`

```
1,2,3,4,5
12,13,14,15,16
11,17,18,19,20
22,23,24,25,26
22,27,28,29,21
30,31,32,33,34
```

I'm trying with awk to complete this, but no luck. I want the output as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s"(i%5==0?RS:FS),$i}' file
1,2,3,4,5
12,13,14,15,16
11,17,18,19,20
22,23,24,25,26
22,27,28,29,21
30,31,32,33,34
```

Comment: @jonte, can you please explain this part `printf "%s"(i%5==0?RS:FS),$i`

Comment: `printf` use this format: `"%s"` select the value `$i`.  `i%5==0` is `i` in a pattern `0,5,10,15..`, if so use `RS`=new line, if not use `FS`=comma. Its just a `if` `then` `else` test.

Comment: the init input file has space in lines and only two lines in sample. But now it has been changed,not sure, if you change it, or OP did the updates. If space in line, your code will be failed.

Comment: @BMW It did have 3 line in the sample all the time. OP did not use code tags correctly, so it showed up wrong.  Just take a look at edit history.

Comment: @BMV Look at Edit history, then click edit for the first post, to see how OP did try to format it, and there you see the three original lines.

Comment: Perfect, we can review the edit history, that's good function. Yes, I can see the init version with two lines only, but after you edit it, the sample file was changed to three lines.

Comment: @BMW You are not looking correctly. The init version has three lines, not two.  You need to click the edit button for the first version to see it, not the edit button for my edit. Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22955534/edit/affaaac1-e7d3-4319-8226-6350d3140e18

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
sed 's/,/ /g' file|xargs -n5 |sed 's/ /,/g'

1,2,3,4,5
12,13,14,15,16
11,17,18,19,20
22,23,24,25,26
22,27,28,29,21
30,31,32,33,34
```

#### Explanation.

1) sed command: `sed 's/,/ /g'` and `sed 's/ /,/g'` used to replace characters.

2) xargs -n5 :

```
   -n max-args, --max-args=max-args
          Use at most max-args arguments per command line.  Fewer than max-args arguments will be
          used if the size (see the -s option) is exceeded, unless the -x  option  is  given,  in
          which case xargs will exit.
```

Comment: great. can you please explain about `xargs -n5` , i haven't used sed commands.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grep`:

```
grep -oP '([^,]+,){4}[^,]+' inputfile
```

or

```
grep -oE '([^,]+,){4}[^,]+' inputfile
```

or

```
egrep -o '([^,]+,){4}[^,]+' inputfile
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
1,2,3,4,5
12,13,14,15,16
11,17,18,19,20
22,23,24,25,26
22,27,28,29,21
30,31,32,33,34
```

Comment: @GanzRicanz Do you have `egrep`?

Comment: yes i have @devnull , but egrep with flag o also not recoganized

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have modulo 5 elements in total, and that you want to fill each line completely, you could also use `tr` and `paste` like this:

```
<file tr , \\n | paste -d, - - - - -
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5
12,13,14,15,16
11,17,18,19,20
22,23,24,25,26
22,27,28,29,21
30,31,32,33,34
```